# How to detect repainting or signal disappearing in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have an indicator which gives Buy and Sell signals but it only gives signal when bar closes. This is achieved with `barstate.isconfirmed` condition. But now I want the signal to give the Signal whenever it comes during the bar, but if it disappears until bar close I also want the alert to show that the signal disappeared.

So for example I have an indicator on BTCUSD 4H candles. It gives a "BUY" alert in first hour of the candle. But this "BUY" signals goes away after first hour and doesn't come again. I want that, when the 4H candle closes it should give additional alert of "DISAPPEAR" if the "BUY" doesn't remain. But if it remains then it should give alert of "CONFIRMED".

So far I have tried with the following code snippet:

```
buyFlag = false
sellFlag = false

if indicatorBuyTrigger
    buyFlag := true
    alert("BUY")
if indicatorSellTrigger
    sellFlag := true
    alert("SELL")

if barstate.isconfirmed
    if indicatorBuyTrigger
        alert("BUY_CONFIRMED")
        buyFlag:= false
    else
        if buyFlag
            alert("BUY_DISAPPEAR")
            buyFlag:= false
    if indicatorSellTrigger
        alert("SELL_CONFIRMED")
        sellFlag:= false
    else
        if sellFlag
            alert("SELL_DISAPPEAR")
            sellFlag:= false
```

With this code the intial "BUY","SELL", "BUY_CONFIRMED", "SELL_CONFIRMED" are working fine, but the "DISAPPEAR" alerts aren't working. I get the alerts of "BUY" or "SELL" instantaneously, and if it remains for the whole candle then I get the "CONFIRMED" signals at candle close. But if the signals disappear in-between the bar then I don't get the "DISAPPEAR" alert.

So how can I get it to work so that I can detect that repainting has occurred or the Signal condition were satisfied in between the candle but not on candle close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can try this example

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © protradingart

//@version=5
indicator("Get Disappeared Signal", overlay = true)

fastSMA = ta.sma(close, 1)
slowSMA = ta.sma(close, 3)

long = ta.crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)
short = ta.crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)

plot(fastSMA, color = color.lime)
plot(slowSMA, color = color.red)

plotshape(long, color=color.lime, location = location.belowbar)
plotshape(short, color=color.red)


varip wasLong = false

if barstate.isnew
    wasLong := false
else 
    if long
        wasLong := true


plotshape(wasLong, color = color.yellow)

if wasLong and not long
    alert("Disappeared Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if long
    alert("Confirmed Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: Thanks! the `varip` declaration seems to have solved it. This solution works and even the solution that I tried in the question works when `buyFlag` and `sellFlag` were declared as `varip` variables.